# windows mobile 6.5 wceload.exe - how to set the target installation directory?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework

Is there a way to set the target installation directory as parameter for CAB file when using the wceload.exe tool? I use wceload.exe tool to perform the silent install (with /silent and /noui params).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately no.  [WCELOAD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms926281) has no "target install folder" ability.  It either uses what's in the INF file, or if not present in the INF, it pops up a dialog for the user to select.

The work-around I've used, while seemingly heavy-handled, was to write my own installer app that replaces WCELOAD using the [CAB Installer SDK](http://www.opennetcf.com/Products/CABInstallerSDK/tabid/272/Default.aspx) (the SDK comes with an example app) and then call it instead of WCELOAD.